# How to display page using sinatra and rspec

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rspec2

I'm using Rspec to test a Sinatra application.
Sometimes things go wrong (tests doesn't pass) and I would like to be able to see the page, without much effort(equivalent of 'Then show me the page' in cucumber/webrat (I think)),

Comment: I usually do `raise last_reponse.body.inspect`. But this isn't *without much effort*.

Comment: That alright effort wise, but I would like an html view

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/4496664/how-can-we-generate-html-file-from-rspec does this help?

Comment: @Kashyap, no it doesn't help. That's a useful tip anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rack::Test doesn't have the ability to do what you're asking, but [Capybara](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/0.3.9/Capybara/SaveAndOpenPage) does. You'll also need the [Launchy gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/launchy) so that the browser opens when it hits the save_and_open_page method.